# Drill Through In jasper Report

Tags: dynamic, jasper-reports

H guys ,

We are creating the report in that we have one pie chart and  one table component.
When we click on the pie chart then corresponding details should appear in the table component.

Please guys can any one help me

Thanks in advance

B. Rama Krishna

Answer (score 0):

To call another report (with the table) from your report you can use a hyperlink (right click on your chart and select hyperlink). You should probably use a hyperlink of type reportExecution and pass the target report path _report and any parameters. This is covered in some detail in the ireport user guide which can be found in the jasper community website or just google reportexecution hyperlink jasper e.g.

http://alexandru-ersenie.com/2009/10/22/passing-parameters-between-jasper-reports-using-ireport-and-jasperserver/

Comment: Sorry for the Delay. the answer you have given is good but the solution which you have given is when we click on the Main report Hyper-link the detail report will open in the Another page  or else it will load in the same page by over riding the main report . We want to show the detail report in the same page  with out over riding the main page .

Comment: Solution to this would be to create a dashboard consisting of several reports if you have the paid version or the report you call could be a composite of the original report and the detail panel

Comment: You may think that you can press something in one report and effect a subreport but I don't think this is possible - see the Jaspersoft-Studio-User-Guide.pdf (or the iReport guide) which you get with the installation - 3.8 Anchors, Bookmarks, and Hyperlinks or look at my comment above

Comment: thanks for reply i will try further and let you know